# How do I detect symbols in a string using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I am developing a web application for a school and the have things like class_name and course_name.  A course_name is the parent of a  class_name, hence the class_name must contain the course_name.  For instance:

```
course_name = "Weeklies"
class_name = "Weeklies talks with Superstars"
```

The above case would be perfect and correct.

However, there are times a user will create a course_name with symbols that mess up the word boundary regular expression I have set for class_name ( \b\b ).  Having the metacharacters of regular expressions in a course_name makes the word boundary return False everytime since symbols are not words.

QUESTION:

How do I check if a course_name contains symbols/metacharacters in Python and if it does, I want to return False else True?

-Mark

Comment: This doesn't smell quite right. (1) Are you building a database from this information? could the data be put into rows in a csv file and loaded directly? (2) Does this data live in a configuration file -- a .INI file, maybe? Parse it using ConfigParser or write the file as json. (3) Do you as the developer have some control over this data or is it made by users?

Comment: It's controlled by the users.  So if the user created "Weekelies (Screening)" as the course_name and using my \bWeeklies (Screening)\b regular expression, it would fail as the parenthesis is not a word.  How do I detect symbols/metacharacters in a string?  I want to prevent the user from typing a course_name with symbols and metacharacters in them.

Answer (score 1):

[`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape)

Comment: Hi Ignacio, thanks for your quick reply.  I do not want to return a string with non-aplphanumerics backslashed.  I want to check if it contains metacharacters or not.  Please refer to my comment above

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a general purpose solution... Just replace the regular expression with a suitable grammar.

```
if not re.match(str, r'[\w\d\ ]+'):
    # valid
```